# Can't run PHP 8.1 and NodeJS 16 with webpack using docker compose - node not found

Tags: php, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm having a hard time configuring docker for my needs, I need 2 things:

1. a docker image for PHP 8.1/Apache along with xDebug, this part works fine, it's the docker service named **web**
2. another service based on NodeJS 16 that needs to perform 2 things:

- run npm install
- run webpack 5 in watch mode: `node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch`

So I used to Dockerfile, the first in the root directory for PHP, the other stored in config/docker/services/webpack

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "docker.local:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
  webpack:
    image: node:16
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config/docker/services/webpack/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - web
```

The main Dockerfile in the root directory:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

COPY config/docker/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY . /var/www/html/
COPY config/docker/*.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Now my `config/docker/service/webpack/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

COPY package.json /home/node/app
COPY package-lock.json /home/node/app
COPY webpack.config.js /home/node/app

CMD npm install && node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch
```

I didn’t see any errors on COPY when running `docker compose build`

Now when running docker compose up I get this output:

```
Attaching to my_project-web-1, my_project-webpack-1
my_project-web-1      | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
my_project-web-1      | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
my_project-web-1      | [Thu Jul 14 10:58:55.027174 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/8.1.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
my_project-web-1      | [Thu Jul 14 10:58:55.027201 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
my_project-webpack-1  | /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
my_project-webpack-1 exited with code 127
```

If I type `docker compose run webpack sh` I land on the PHP container.

When I type CTRL+C to stop the containers I get this:

```
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Container my_project_webpack_run_68483587fb5b  Stopped                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container my_project_web-webpack-1                 Stopped                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container my_project_web_webpack_run_08823c788f9d  Stopped                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container my_project-1                     Stopped
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just to run some tests, I added the redis image as a service and typing `docker compose run redis /bin/bash` landed me on the redis container, not PHPs so there’s something I don’t get.

Comment: If you have both `image:` and `build:` together, it tells Compose to build the image and then give it the specified name; you're calling the image your Dockerfile builds `node:16` even though it's not the official Node image.  Might you at some point have built a custom image but accidentally labeled it with the base image of your other image?  If you delete the `image:` line from your Compose file, and `docker rmi node:16-alpine`, does it work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze It doesn't change anything. I've added the main Dockerfile for PHP as well as the output when I stop the containers.